Issue With HibernateTransactionManager while migrating Spring MVC applicaiton from spring 4.x/hiberate3.x/java1.8 to spring6.1/Hibernate5.x/Java17
I am migrating lagacy spring mvc application with spring4.x/hiberate3.x/java1.8 in tomcat8.5 server to spring6.1/Hiberate5.6.x/java17/tomcat10.1.3. as part of this process , I replaced JOTM transactions with spring based transactions with HibernateTransactionManager. Once the deployment is completed in tomcat, I am getting below error in the log files.Any help from someone would be greatly appreciated.
Error:
Pre-bound JDBC Connection found! HibernateTransactionManager does not support running within DataSourceTransactionManager if told to manage the DataSource itself. It is recommended to use a single HibernateTransactionManager for all transactions on a single DataSource, no matter whether Hibernate or JDBC access.#~
org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: Pre-bound JDBC Connection found! HibernateTransactionManager does not support running within DataSourceTransactionManager if told to manage the DataSource itself. It is recommended to use a single HibernateTransactionManager for all transactions on a single DataSource, no matter whether Hibernate or JDBC access.
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:470) ~[spring-orm-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:532) ~[spring-tx-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:405) ~[spring-tx-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:604) ~[spring-tx-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:373) ~[spring-tx-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at jdk.proxy3.$Proxy167.process(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at com.sandp.smartwork.common.processor.MessageDispatcher.invokeRequest(MessageDispatcher.java:396) ~[classes/:?]
at com.sandp.smartwork.common.processor.MessageDispatcher.doProcess(MessageDispatcher.java:126) ~[classes/:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:355) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:379) [spring-tx-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) [spring-tx-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) [spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) [spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:720) [spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at com.sandp.smartwork.common.processor.MessageDispatcher$$SpringCGLIB$$0.doProcess() [classes/:?]
at com.sandp.smartwork.core.service.message.MessageProcessorMDB.processSPESBNormalizedMessage(MessageProcessorMDB.java:290) [classes/:?]
at com.sandp.smartwork.core.service.message.MessageProcessorMDB.onMessage(MessageProcessorMDB.java:198) [classes/:?]
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dispatch(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:1434) [activemq-client-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.dispatch(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:131) [activemq-client-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.iterate(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:202) [activemq-client-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:133) [activemq-client-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:48) [activemq-client-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
2024-10-24 14:19:55,667 INFO  [com.sandp.smartwork.common.processor.MessageDispatcher] ActiveMQ Session Task-1 MS-1729793990320-1~#[invokeRequest failed for - beanName:ProcessRatingRelease] Pre-bound JDBC Connection found! HibernateTransactionManager does not support running within DataSourceTransactionManager if told to manage the DataSource itself. It is recommended to use a single HibernateTransactionManager for all transactions on a single DataSource, no matter whether Hibernate or JDBC access.#~
org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: Pre-bound JDBC Connection found! HibernateTransactionManager does not support running within DataSourceTransactionManager if told to manage the DataSource itself. It is recommended to use a single HibernateTransactionManager for all transactions on a single DataSource, no matter whether Hibernate or JDBC access.
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:470) ~[spring-orm-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:532) ~[spring-tx-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:405) ~[spring-tx-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:604) ~[spring-tx-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:373) ~[spring-tx-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at jdk.proxy3.$Proxy167.createErrorResponse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at com.sandp.smartwork.common.processor.MessageDispatcher.handleException(MessageDispatcher.java:452) ~[classes/:?]
at com.sandp.smartwork.common.processor.MessageDispatcher.invokeRequest(MessageDispatcher.java:425) ~[classes/:?]
at com.sandp.smartwork.common.processor.MessageDispatcher.doProcess(MessageDispatcher.java:126) ~[classes/:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:355) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) ~[spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:379) [spring-tx-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) [spring-tx-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) [spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) [spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:720) [spring-aop-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at com.sandp.smartwork.common.processor.MessageDispatcher$$SpringCGLIB$$0.doProcess() [classes/:?]
at com.sandp.smartwork.core.service.message.MessageProcessorMDB.processSPESBNormalizedMessage(MessageProcessorMDB.java:290) [classes/:?]
at com.sandp.smartwork.core.service.message.MessageProcessorMDB.onMessage(MessageProcessorMDB.java:198) [classes/:?]
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dispatch(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:1434) [activemq-client-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.dispatch(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:131) [activemq-client-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.iterate(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:202) [activemq-client-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:133) [activemq-client-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:48) [activemq-client-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
Dispatcher servelet configuration:

<import resource="processorConfig.xml" />
<import resource="persistence.xml" />
<import resource="dao.xml" />
<import resource="applicationContext-Messaging.xml" />

<context:component-scan
base-package="com.sandp.smartwork.core.webservice, com.sandp.smartwork.fgr.webservice " />


<context:property-placeholder location="file:${catalina.home}/env_cs.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />  

<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory" />

<bean
    class="com.sandp.smartwork.common.configuration.CustomWsdlDefinitionHandlerAdapter" id="CustomWsdlDefinitionHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="requestURI" value="${services.providerurl.http}"/>
    <property name="schemaLoc" value="${sp.schema.url}"/>       
</bean>

<bean id="messageDispatcher"
    class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher" />

<bean id="messageReceiver"
    class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher" />



<sws:annotation-driven />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping">
    <description>An endpoint mapping strategy that looks for @Endpoint and
        @PayloadRoot annotations.Each Implementation class acts as an
        EndPoint</description>
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WsdlDefinitionHandlerAdapter">
</bean> 



<bean id="core/Committee"
    class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.SimpleWsdl11Definition">
    <constructor-arg value="/WEB-INF/classes/wsdl/core/Committee.wsdl" index="0"/>
</bean> 


<bean id="EPAD/Organization"
    class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.SimpleWsdl11Definition">
    <constructor-arg value="/WEB-INF/classes/wsdl/v3/Organization.wsdl" index="0"/>                                                   
</bean>

portion of processorConfig.xml:

<context:property-placeholder location="file:${catalina.home}/env_cs.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
context:annotation-config/

my service class that has @Transactional:
@Service
public class MessageDispatcher {
private static LoggerClient logger = new LoggerClient(MessageDispatcher.class);
// private SPMessageExchange replyMessageExchange;
private SPESBNormalizedMessage nm = null;

public MessageDispatcher() {
}
@Transactional
public SPESBNormalizedMessage doProcess(SPESBNormalizedMessage message) {
    boolean isTransactionRolledback=false;
    try {
            replayDocument = invokeRequest(requestDoc, RequestContext.messageRequestContext, beanName);// this is another method in same class
                if (isErrorResponse(replayDocument)) {
                    logger.logMessage("debug", "process failed, rolling back the changes...", methodName);
                
                    isTransactionRolledback=true;
                    logger.logMessage("info", "changes rolledback successfully...", methodName);
                } else {
                    logger.logMessage("debug", "process successful, committing the changes...", methodName);
                
                    logger.logMessage("info", "changes committed successfully...", methodName);
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                logger.logException(e, "invokeRequest failed for - beanName:" + beanName);
                isTransactionRolledback=true;
            
                logger.logMessage("warn", "Rollback effort done, updating the response...", methodName);
            
            }
        if(isTransactionRolledback) {
            throw new CustomRollbackException(true,nm);
        }
        return something;
    
}

}

my peristence.xml :

transaction manager i used :


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
